# Why does mutual exclusion require atomic operation?

Tags: multithreading, mutex, semaphore

I have following example for mutual exclusion:

```
int mutex = 0;
   Thread A: 
   while(TRUE):
       while(mutex==1);
       #critical
       mutex=1;
    
   Thread B:
   int mutex = 0;
    while(TRUE):
       while(mutex==0);
       #critical
       mutex=0;
```

Why do operations have to be atomic here? Maybe a scenario at assembly level would be helpful to understand.

Let's say I entered Thread A and finished CS and set mutex=1.

```
MOV [MUTEX],1
```

I mean it is only one instruction, what would go wrong here?

Comment: "I mean it is only one instruction" - consider if the CPU instruction is reordered by the compiler or the processor itself (see: speculative execution) - or if you're using a non-atomic type (such as `uint128_t` on a 32-bit processor).

Comment: Also, consider if two threads are **both** at the `MOV [MUTEX],1` instruction when the OS scheduler interrupts them - or if they're executing concurrently in an SMP (multi-core or multi-socket machine) where true-concurrency is a thing (instead of a multi-threaded program operating in a single-thread computer, like the 1990s Pentiums).

Comment: @NateEldredge yes I did mistake, would make no sense.

Comment: Note that your example is pretty boring, because it requires that the threads always alternate executing the critical section.  This won't be useful in a lot of applications. Suppose the critical section accesses some shared resource.  A has just finished using the shared resource but soon finds it needs it again.  Meanwhile B is off doing something unrelated that doesn't use the resource at all. Ideally A should just take the mutex back immediately and do its work, but in your model, it can't do so until B gets around to taking a turn.

Comment: So if you want to design the program so that either thread can take the mutex when it's available, without a pointless delay, you'll find more possible races starting to come up, and it'll be more clear that atomicity is needed.

Comment: @NateEldredge yes with other examples I can understand atomic operations. For example the normal use of locks or semaphore, there might be lost decrement/increment.

Answer (score 1):

```
MOV [MUTEX], 1
```

would likely succeed in setting a mutex, how would you know if it was already set?  Ok, so:

```
       LOCK:
1:            MOV R0, [MUTEX]
2:            MOV [MUTEX], 1
3:            CMP R0, 0
4:            BNE LOCK
5:            RET
```

That looks a bit better, but what if, just after instruction 1, but before instruction 2, an interrupt was recognized, and the interrupt handler locked the same mutex you wanted.  Later, it returns to you, with [MUTEX] now == 1, but your R0 == 0.  Version 3:

```
       LOCK:
0:            DISABLE_INTERRUPTS
1:            MOV R0, [MUTEX]
2:            MOV [MUTEX], 1
3:            CMP R0, 0
4:            BNE LOCK
5:            RESTORE_INTERRUPTS
6:            RET
```

This is all good, until we add a second CPU which will not respect the disabled interrupts.  Thus you either need an atomic which is generally a bad thing, or a way to detect conflicts.   Atomics are dull, but detecting conflicts is kinda cool:

```
LOCK:
        RESERVE [MUTEX] in Cache in a unique state.
        MOV R0, [MUTEX]
        STORE 1 to [MUTEX] only if it still in unique state.
        if [MUTEX] was not exclusive, jump to LOCK
        CMP R0, 0
        BNE LOCK
        ret
```

So, if another processor accessed [MUTEX] while it was in a *unique* state, it would revert to a common state, indicating to this processor that it needs to try again.  This is way hipper because it can work on any kind of cache coherent bus, and its analogue is used in distributed databases and other way higher level software.  This is called load/store exclusive, and would usually look more like:

```
LOCK:
        LOAD.EXCL  R0, [MUTEX]
        STORE.EXCL R1, [MUTEX], 1
        CMP R1, 0       / R1 tells whether the store succeeded.
        BNE LOCK
        CMP R0, 0       / R0 is the value we loaded earlier.
        BNE LOCK
        RET
```

Comment: Some of the issues you mention would not arise in the program given, if we assume the mutex is only used by the two threads shown and not by any interrupt handlers or any other code.  The threads always alternate and never *take* the mutex by themselves, they only wait for the other thread to give it to them.  The mutex has no state where it is available to be taken by either thread.  This is not a very useful algorithm, but I *think* it is safe under mild assumptions about the machine's memory model.

Comment: In the first example the compiler did resort the instructions like Dai mentioned earlier? I would expect Instruction 1 to appear after Instruction 2.

Comment: If you have two threads that are already synchronized, why do you need a mutex?   Its fundamental role is to synchronize, via serialization, independent instruction streams.